# how to listen data from a port already running in my system in java

Tags: java, sockets

Hi
I want to read the data from a port example 1234 which is always listening some application buffers data on that port. Now I have to read that port and print data which is buffered on that port in java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your correctly you wish to read information sent to other application that is listening to specific port. If I am right you actually wish to implement sniffer in java.

In this case I recommend you to use JPcap: http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Good answer to a cryptic question.